# How to use ffmpeg API to set the bitrate of push video stream with c?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have a problem, **broken pipe**. I suspect it is caused by too much push bandwidth. How can I use ffmpeg API to set the bitrate of push video stream? I use C language.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question in the [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/structAVFormatContext.html) document

```
int64_t AVFormatContext::bit_rate
```